# Find the magnitude/length of the cross product of two vectors

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I'm going through past exam questions, and this is one I haven't come across. How can I approach it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of the cross product is given by:

$|a \times b| = |a||b| \sin \theta$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Can you find this angle? Hint: think of the angle between *any* vector along the $z$-axis and the $xy$ plane.